# Bug multiplos modals bootstrap

Tags: html, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, modal

Tenho dois modais na mesma pagina, uma para alterar e outro para remover informações do banco.

O código do primeiro modal é esse:

```
    <!-- Modal Editar -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Alterar Informações Instituição de Insino</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar alterações</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

O código que preenche o modal é esse:

```
    <script>
  $(".btn[data-target='#myModal']").click(function () {
    var columnHeadings = $("thead th").map(function () {
      return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    columnHeadings.pop();
    var columnValues = $(this).parent().siblings().map(function () {
      return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    var modalBody = $('<div id="modalContent"></div>');
    var modalForm = $('<form role="form" name="modalForm" action="/ies/atualizar" method="post"></form>');
    $.each(columnHeadings, function (i, columnHeader) {
      var formGroup = $('<div class="form-group"></div>');
      formGroup.append('<label for="' + columnHeader + '">' + columnHeader + '</label>');
      formGroup.append('<input class="form-control" name="' + columnHeader + i + '" id="' + columnHeader + i + '" value="' + columnValues[i] + '" />');
      modalForm.append(formGroup);
    });
    modalBody.append(modalForm);
    $('.modal-body').html(modalBody);
  });
  $('.modal-footer .btn-primary').click(function () {
    $('form[name="modalForm"]').submit();
  });
</script>
```

Os códigos do segundo modal são esses:

```
<!-- Modal Deletar -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalDeletar">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Deseja Apagar Instituição de Insino?</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Remover</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <script>
  $(".btn[data-target='#modalDeletar']").click(function () {
    var columnHeadings = $("thead th").map(function () {
      return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    columnHeadings.pop();
    var columnValues = $(this).parent().siblings().map(function () {
      return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    var modalBody = $('<div id="modalContentDelete"></div>');
    var modalForm = $('<form role="form" name="modalFormDelete" action="/ies/deletar" method="post"></form>');
    $.each(columnHeadings, function (i, columnHeader) {
      var formGroup = $('<div class="form-group"></div>');
      formGroup.append('<label for="' + columnHeader + '">' + columnHeader + '</label>');
      formGroup.append('<input class="form-control" name="' + columnHeader + i + '" id="' + columnHeader + i + '" value="' + columnValues[i] + '" />');
      modalForm.append(formGroup);
    });
    modalBody.append(modalForm);
    $('.modal-body').html(modalBody);
  });
  $('.modal-footer .btn-primary').click(function () {
    $('form[name="modalForm"]').submit();
  });
</script>
```

O que acontece é o seguinte, quando eu tenho só o modal de editar no código, eu consigo editar normalmente os valores no banco, quando adiciono o modal de deletar, ele passa a não conseguir mais atualizar,  mas o delete funciona normalmente.

O que pode estar causando esse erro?

Comment: Eu faço essa modal de deletar de uma forma mais simples, não precisa fazer a modal na página, chama ela via js.

Comment: Vou postar uma resposta explicando

Answer (score 1):

**Tenho uma modal que aparece dentro de um js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[data-del]').click(function(ev){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if(!$('#confirm-Del').length){
            $('body').append('    Deseja Deletar?  ×    Não há como recuperar dados apagados.   Não Sim    ');

            }
        $('#dataDelOK').attr('href', href);
        $('#confirm-Del').modal({show: true});
        return false;

    });
});
```

**Então chamo ela pelo php:**
< a **data-del**  href="deletar.php?id="> Del< /a>

e faço um link do arquivo js no final da página ou coloco ele dentro da página já, sem ser externo. Coloca a tag "< a >" chamando a página dentro do while.

**Explicando o script**:
No código js, se o botão com o atributo "**data-sair**" for clicado chama o código. Que cria na página uma modal referente ao id. E há dois botões com 2 atributos de sair ou dar ok que chama o php de delete pra deletar. Ou alguma outra página, no meu caso crio uma conexão com o bd, e apago o id referente.

funcionando online: https://jsfiddle.net/PH7Jack/1u29gpfb/